# Free particle wave function at $t=0$ with constant term

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, time-evolution

What does it mean for a free particle wave function at $t=0$, to have a form $$Ψ(x,0)=C+Ce^{ikx}?$$ If the aim is to construct time evolution of the particle through its representation in $k$-space (i.e. through Fourier Transform), do we need to introduce a time-dependent exponential in the first term of the Wave Function and treat it as a component of the superposition? If we do not, and if there is no other way of, so to speak, normalising the function, it seems that the integral would never converge.

This question is from the perspective of a complete beginner - so feel free to point out any fundamental errors of concept too.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Psi(x)=Ae^{ik_1 x}+Be^{ik_2 x},\\
k_1=0$$